# How to get TOP larger tables in SQL Server 2000 and their sizes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Is there a way via T-SQL to get the larger tables and their respective size in a SQL Server 2000 engine?

Comment: SQL 2000?  It might be time to consider an upgrade.

Comment: Totally agree! But it´s a long story that includes government bureaucracy

Comment: Sql Server 2000 is **end of life**, and has been for more than 10 years now. It hasn't had any patches in that time... not even for critical security issues. _Continuing to use this server is dangerous and irresponsible._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this script works with SQL Server 2000 even if `sp_msforeachtable` was not documented

```
CREATE TABLE #SpaceUsed (
 TableName sysname
,NumRows BIGINT
,ReservedSpace VARCHAR(50)
,DataSpace VARCHAR(50)
,IndexSize VARCHAR(50)
,UnusedSpace VARCHAR(50)
)
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)
SET @str =  'exec sp_spaceused ''?'''
INSERT INTO #SpaceUsed
EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1=@str

SELECT * FROM #SpaceUsed ORDER BY ReservedSpace DESC
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thank you so much!!